# Collection with single entity restriction

Tags: mongodb, constraints

I would like to create collection where only one entity should be stored.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to create restrictions for this collection on db level?
2. What are the best practices for CRUD application dealing with such collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to be sure that new documents will respect your schema. This feature appears in 3.2, but was modified since 3.6 with use of JSON schema. Check the right doc version.